# package spark does not exist

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, spark-java

I'm just starting to learn Java.

I am using IntelliJ to create a SparkJava (see: sparkjava.com) app using openjdk 17.  I followed the tutorial instructions outlined in "Setting up Spark with Maven" (https://sparkjava.com/tutorials/maven-setup).  I believe the instructions are very outdated because they did not work.  After some googling, I finally just arrived at the following code and POM.xml.  When I build the project, I get an error: `java: package spark does not exist`

I don't know what to do.

- I added the dependency to my POM.xml.
- I added the *apache.spark.core_2.13* library via Project Structure.

I googled "IntelliJ package does not exist" but couldn't find a helpful answer.  Most everyone said to "add the dependency to the POM" but I've already done that.
I googled "add package to Java project IntelliJ" but after clicking a number of linkis, I couldn't find a helpful answer.  I tried a few of the suggestions, but none resolved this problem.

I think I am missing something fundamental here, like somehow I'm not telling IntelliJ where to find the spark code.

src/main/java/Sparky.java

```
import static spark.Spark.*;

public class Sparky {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World");
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>sparky</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't configure IntelliJ for Maven properly. Either your project is not a Maven project (as far as IntelliJ is concerned, even if the structure of the project is valid for Maven), or you're missing an IntelliJ plugin or something. Look at [IntelliJ's doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html) on how to create and manage a Maven project.

Comment: Thank you but that did not solve the problem.  I've followed those steps.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency package was completely wrong.  It was pointing at Apache Spark, not Spark Java.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```